# Error while trying to add up purchases between two inputed dates

Tags: python, python-3.x, date

The instructions are the following:
"2 dates are entered and the total purchases between those dates is shown, including the purchases made on those dates."

I have the following list:

```
list_purchases=[{'id':'123','name':'Luis', 'surname':'Henderson', 'price':16000, 'date': "(2022, 3, 12)"},{''id':'123','name':'Luis', 'surname':'Henderson', 'price':4000, 'date': "(2022, 12, 1)"}]
```

And I've tried the following code but I don't know how to arrange it in order to make a `for loop` which goes through those specific dates and add up the purchases made.

```
def dates_purchases():
     year=int(input("Enter year of first date: "))
     month = int(input("Enter month of first date: "))
     day = int(input("Enter day of first date: "))
     first_date=date(year,month,day)

     year2=int(input("Enter year of second date: "))
     month2 = int(input("Enter month of second date: "))
     day2 = int(input("Enter day of second date: "))     
     second_date=date(year2,month2,day2)

        
     for purchases in range(first_date,second_date):
           sum=+purchases['price']
           print('The total cost of the purchases made between those dates is:',sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to a pandas Dataframe, perform filtering operations, then sum up the price.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

list_purchases = [{'id':'123','name':'Luis', 'surname':'Henderson', 'price':16000, 'date': "(2022, 3, 12)"},{'id':'123','name':'Luis', 'surname':'Henderson', 'price':4000, 'date': "(2022, 12, 1)"}]

# Convert to DataFrame and datetime format
purchase_data = pd.DataFrame(list_purchases)
purchase_data["date"] = pd.to_datetime(purchase_data["date"], format="(%Y, %m, %d)")

# Query for first and last date (you can set as input, let me pre-define it here)
first_date = datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 12)
last_date = datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 1)

# Filter for date between first_date and last_date inclusive
purchase_data_filter = purchase_data[((first_date <= purchase_data["date"])) & (purchase_data["date"] <= last_date)]

result = purchase_data_filter.price.sum()
```